# One or more child tests had errors, Exception doesn't have a stacktrace

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am fairly new to unit testing and am trying to conduct a test using Nunit but get the following message when running the test plan.

I have tried to step through the code, however it doesnt hit a breakpoint, so I am guessing at the moment that its failing before its hitting the Test Method

> One or more child tests had errors
>     Exception doesn't have a stacktrace

The code below is what I am working with but cannot seem to get this to work;

```
[TestFixture]
class PaymentServicetTest
{

    [Test]
    public void MakePayment()
    {
        var paymentRequestDetails = new MakePaymentRequest
        {
            Amount = 876.36m,
            CreditorAccountNumber = "12345678",
            DebtorAccountNumber = "87654321",
            PaymentDate = DateTime.Now,
            PaymentScheme = PaymentScheme.Chaps

        };
        var paymentService = new PaymentService();
        var result = paymentService.MakePayment(paymentRequestDetails);
        Assert.True(result.Success);
    }

}
```

I would be grateful if someone can point me in the direction of what I am doing wrong and how to fix it

Thanks

Simon

Comment: Debugged the test?

Comment: When it was continually failing, I tried to step through it but its not hitting an  breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Your test fixture class is not public and therefore invalid. The error you are seeing is probably on the assembly and is merely reporting that some child test or tests failed - in this case the fixture.

You don't say how you run tests* but I'm guessing it's via the Visual Studio adapter, which only reports errors on test cases, not fixture. The adapter has to translate NUnit concepts to what Visual Studio understands and unfortunately that does not include test fixtures or suites of tests.

*As a new user of NUnit, you may not recognize the need to say how you are running your tests when you describe a problem. It's very common because new users often only know about a single way to run tests. The NUnit team supports at least a half dozen (depends how you count things) and there are many more from third parties, so it's a good idea to say exactly how you run tests.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened because I had copied, pasted and amended a test. I'm not sure why this caused a failure in the test runner but deleting the test and manually re-adding it without pasting another test fixed it.